# Getting the Azure ML environment build status

Tags: python-3.x, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk

I am trying to set up a ML pipeline on Azure ML using the Python SDK.
I have scripted the creation of a custom environment from a DockerFile as follows

```
from azureml.core import Environment
from azureml.core.environment import ImageBuildDetails
from other_modules import workspace, env_name, dockerfile

custom_env : Environment = Environment.from_dockerfile(name=env_name, dockerfile=dockerfile)
                      
custom_env.register(workspace=workspace)

build : ImageBuildDetails = custom_env.build(workspace=workspace)

build.wait_for_completion()
```

However, the `ImageBuildDetails` object that the [`build`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.environment.environment?view=azure-ml-py#build-workspace--image-build-compute-none-) method returns invariably times out while executing the last `wait_for_completion()` line, ... likely due to network constraints that I cannot change.

So, how can I possibly check the build status via the SDK in a way that doesn't exclusively depend on the returned `ImageBuildDetails` object?

Answer (score 2):

**My first suggestion would be to use:**

`build.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)`

This will help you debug better rather than assuming you have network issues, as the images can take quite a long time to build, and from my experience creating environments it's very likely you may have an issue with related to your Dockerfile.

**A good alternative option is to build your docker image locally and optionally push it to the container registry associated with the workspace:**

```html
from azureml.core import Environment
myenv = Environment(name="myenv")
registered_env = myenv.register(workspace)
registered_env.build_local(workspace, useDocker=True, pushImageToWorkspaceAcr=True)
```

**However another preferred method is to create an environment object from an environment specification YAML file:**

```
from_conda_specification(name, file_path)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-environments#use-conda-dependencies-or-pip-requirements-files

This should return the `Environment` and to verify it has been created:

```html
for name,env in ws.environments.items():
    print("Name {} \t version {}".format(name,env.version))

restored_environment = Environment.get(workspace=ws,name="myenv",version="1")

print("Attributes of restored environment")
restored_environment
```